# Album added to iTunes library but not listed in Albums and Songs section

Tags: itunes, album

I added a new album to my iTunes (version 11). It has been copied to my Media folder and it plays fine. But it's not listed in my Albums, Artists and Songs sections. I would like to see the artwork in my Albums or list of songs.

I'm able to find the album by searching. What to do? Any ideas?

I believe that adding it again might help, but how do I remove it from my library when it is not present anywhere except search results?

Comment: if you can find the tracks/album by searching for it they must be in your Mediathek maybe it is placed where you don't expect it to be. I'm thinking about Sort Album Artist / Sort Album Name. They some times are different From Album Artist / Album Name. so to verify search for them then rightclick->edit and have a look what the Sorted Album Name is.

Answer (score 2):

1. Try pressing <kbd>command</kbd>+ <kbd>L</kbd> while the song is playing, this will take you to the song/album in your library.
2. Then right click and choose "**Get Info**" to verify the `metadata` for the song & album.

It may not be displaying as expected if the `metadata` for the song doesn't match the filenames.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to search in the playlist "Recently Added" for the items you have added. If they appear in there, right click the items and click on the "Options" tab and set "Media Type" to "Music".

Answer (score 2):

1. Find the song in iTunes:

   - In the search tool in iTunes 11, type the song name to find the song. Once it is displayed, you should be able to click **once** on the result to go to the song.
   - Alternatively, you can press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> while the song is playing as described by @DavidLumpkin.
2. One the song has been found, right-click on it and choose `Get Info`.
3. In the `Info` tab make sure that the `Name`, `Artist`, and `Album` fields contain the correct information.

   - If there is any text - even a space - in the `Album Artist` field (highlighted in red), **the song will be sorted under the `Album Artist`, instead of the `Artist`**. To fix this, either leave the `Album Artist` field blank, or populate it with the same information that is in the `Artist` field.
   - See screenshot:
     [image: iTunes Info tab]
4. In the `Sorting` tab, make sure that the `Sort Name`, `Sort Artist`, and `Sort Album` match the `Name`, `Artist`, and `Album`.

   - iTunes will sort the song under the sorting information given in this tab.
   - Again, note that if you have any text in the `Album Artist` and `Sort Album Artist` fields,  **the song will be sorted under the `Album Artist`, instead of the `Artist`**.
   - See screenshot:
     [image: iTunes Sorting tab]

*Note that I am not currently on a Mac computer with iTunes installed and have thus taken the two screenshots above from the internet. I do not own the screenshots.*

Answer (score 1):

In your phone go to **Settings** then **Music** then in **Library** choose **Sort Albums By Title**.

Check your Music and all your albums would be listed.

Answer (score 0):

I found them under compilations.

Answer (score 0):

Some albums need a little more info: add names in the sort areas, and check the "Show Composer in all Views" check box. Worked for me.

[image: Scrrenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Under get info - make sure that the check box 'compilation' is unchecked. This will force the album to appear as an album and not a compilation..

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that if I have two albums with different names but the exact same "sort as" under the "album" field in the Sorting tab, that one of the two albums will not appear in the Column Browser. For example, let's say I have one called Album A and another called Album B. If get info on a group of Album A songs and go to the Sorting tab, let's say it shows **album** = "Album A" and under that **sort as** = "Album 1". Now if I get info on a group of Album B songs and go to the Sorting tab, let's say it shows **album** = "Album B" and under that **sort as** = "Album 1". If that happens. Album B will not appear in the Album list in the column browser. But if I re-open the Album B songs and change **sort as** = "Album 2" (providing it's unique) then Album B will now appear.

In my opinion the sorting field should be used for sorting ONLY, but it doesn't appear to be designed that way - or else it's a bug. Based on the way the query works, it will lump two albums of different names under the SAME ALBUM NAME if the **sort as** field under album are not unique.